# Updated nested array in svelte writeable object arrays

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I am using svelte writable that consists of an array of objects. Each object contains an array (models). I want to update the array models by adding a new model to it.

Here is my svelte writable:

```
export const dummyCarsData = writable([
    { id: 1, company: "volkswagen", models: ["Polo GT", "Tiguan"] },
    { id: 2, company: "BMW", models: ["M2", "X3",] },
])
```

I attempted to update the `models` array and add a new model using the following:

```
const handleAddCar = () => { data.companyDetails.models.push(newCar); 
dummyCarsData.update((currentData) => [...currentData,currentData[0].models: [...currentData[0].models,newCar]] ); 

console.log(data.companyDetails,$dummyCarsData);
```

But it is givving errors

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/mohdasim/code/myapp/src/routes/details/[companyId]/+page.svelte",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type 'string[] | { id: number; company: string; models: string[]; } | [...string[], string]' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; company: string; models: string[]; }'.\n  Type 'string[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: number; company: string; models: string[]; }': id, company, models",
    "source": "js",
    "startLineNumber": 13,
    "startColumn": 42,
    "endLineNumber": 13,
    "endColumn": 56
}]
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to correctly update the nested `models` array?

Comment: Please clean up your code and format it. It does not even appear to be syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `dummyCarsData.update` function more understandable if you run it over multiple lines.

```js
const handleAddCar = () => {
  dummyCarsData.update((currentData) => {
    currentData[0].models = [...currentData[0].models, newCar]
    return currentData
  })
}
```

See working code in the Svelte REPL here:

https://svelte.dev/repl/8a5f76e1a1f8469d8aba2ebbcc37372e?version=4.0.1